# How to open the Intellij IDEA api documentation side panel

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij IDEA has a helpful side panel showing the JavaDoc of the method under the curser. No i have accidentally clicked on the close X and the panel is gone and I don't know how to reopen it.

Not the first time I lost a tool panel like this .

Does anybody know how to open it again?

**UPDATE 1:**

@stephen-friedrich suggested View -> Tool Windows -> Documentation but that only shows when the panel is open / docked:

[image: Documentation showing]

If you close the panel the Documentation disappears.

[image: Documentation not showing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the default key mapping, at least on linux, you can toggle if the QuickDoc should be floating or as a panel with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> (twice, first time launches it floating, second pins it as a panel)

Comment: Double tap — who would have thought. Thanks, that worked.

Answer (score 1):

Menu: View -> Tool Windows -> Documentation

Comment: That menu entry doesn't actually show unless the is panel is docked. See my update. But thanks, your comment helped in better understanding the problem.